# Impossible to retrive the plot outline for films with an "aka"

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I need to extract the imdb "plot outline" (storyline) of some movies. For most of them I get it with:

```
description = movie.get('plot outline')
```

However it return an empty string for some movies (despite having a storyline when I look at it manually on the IMDb website).
Most of them are movies with a different title an original title and an "aka" (but not all of them)
For example: 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185584/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

I tried to look at the object return by the API using

```
pprint (vars(m))
```

and it does not contain the "plot outline".

Did everyone else had this issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are various issues and also some bugs in the code.

First of all, remember that search results will not contain any details about a movie: you need to update the information stored in a Movie instance.

Another fact, is that IMDb has changed the way it display the plot outline and the synopsis, which is now also included in the plot page.

As a final note, there's a small bug in the code and also retrieving the synopsis you will also get a warning that should definitely not be there.

Example of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                          

from imdb import IMDb                                                            

ia = IMDb()                                                                      

# Search for  movie; the results will just have a title and little more         
# information.                                                                  
results = ia.search_movie('Osobennosti natsionalnoy rybalki')                    
onr = results[0]                                                                 
print 'Plot from search results: %s' % onr.get('plot outline')                   
print 'Synopsis from search results: %s' % onr.get('synopsis')                   

# Update the default information (main page and plot)                           
ia.update(onr)                                                                   
print 'Plot after the update: %s' % onr.get('plot outline')                      

# Update a specific sub-page                                                    
ia.update(onr, 'synopsis')                                                       
print 'Synopsis after the update: %s' % onr.get('synopsis')
```

Its output:

```
Plot from search results: None Synopsis from search results: None Plot after the update:  Synopsis after the update: This synopsis is too short and may not include the required detailed description of the entire plot. We normally require that synopses be at least 10 lines long. If you have seen this title, please help us by improving and expanding this synopsis.








General Ivolgin, forester Kuzmich, and good-natured Lyova lose their way on a fishing trip and wind up in a neighboring country, where they decide to have a good time anyway but end up leaving their vodka and fishing equipment behind.
```

For sure the synopsis should be parsed directly from the plot outline page (and maybe even used instead of it, if plot outline is missing).
Please, open a bug report in https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/issues